# Can not get the access_token and token_type from TokenProvider commercetools/sdk-auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client, commercetools

**I am trying to integrate the *apollo-client* with *commercetools* but not getting the token and tokentype details, below is the sample code.**

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import SdkAuth, { TokenProvider } from '@commercetools/sdk-auth';

// Create token provider for the commercetools project
const tokenProvider = new TokenProvider({
  sdkAuth: new SdkAuth({
    host: 'https://auth.us-central1.gcp.commercetools.com/',
    projectKey: 'test-ecommerce-store',
    credentials: {
      clientId: '<clinet_id>',
      clientSecret: '<clientSecret>',
    },
    scopes: ['manage_products:test-ecommerce-store'],
  }),
  fetchTokenInfo: sdkAuth => sdkAuth.anonymousFlow(),
});

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'https://api.us-central1.gcp.commercetools.com/test-ecommerce-store/graphql',
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers = {} }) => tokenProvider.getTokenInfo()
  .then(tokenInfo => `${tokenInfo.token_type} ${tokenInfo.access_token}`)
  .then(authorization => ({ headers: { ...headers, authorization } })));

export default new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

**error: "invalid_scope"
error_description: "Permissions exceeded: create_anonymous_token permission required to obtain an anonymous token."
errors: [{code: "invalid_scope",…}]
message: "Permissions exceeded: create_anonymous_token permission required to obtain an anonymous token."
statusCode: 400**

Answer (score 1):

To obtain an access token for an Anonymous Session, the OAuth client needs the create_anonymous_token scope. Does the API client you are using to send this request have this scope?

There is no limit to the number of anonymous tokens you can create.

Answer (score -1):

Looking through your error I can simply identify the issue as follows.

While testing your code you have consumed the allowed threshold of creating anonymous tokens.

Now either you will to wait for a while, probably next day or you can ask support.

Comment: The message is complaining about the permission scope and not a rate limit

Comment: `error_description: "Permissions exceeded: create_anonymous_token permission required to obtain an anonymous token."` says the limit allowed for token generation has exceeded the permitted quota. I have experienced this behavior in APIs multiple times, so I mentioned this as answer. If this exactly is not the reason, there can be other reasons, which can be mentions as answers.
Mine is just one possibility. There was no need for down vote I think.